# Android simple button

Tags: android, button, view, manifest

```
What did i wrong ?
```

I think i wrong on the  intent action  and from startActivity . What should i put to work properly ?

**Main activity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonPainting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPainting);
    buttonPainting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.menupainting.paintingbutton"));      here i put  paintingbutton.java ?
        }
    });
```

**main activity xml :**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPainting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight ="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Paint" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.menupainting"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.menupainting.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.menupainting.paintingbutton"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PAINTINGBUTTON" />   Here on intent action what should i put
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you have any logcat errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line :

`startActivity(new Intent("com.example.menupainting.paintingbutton"));      here i put  paintingbutton.java ?`

to this :

`startActivity(new Intent(this, paintingbutton.class));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, paintingbutton.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.menupainting.paintingbutton"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start another activity with an Intent you should start it as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, GotoActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another activity is started like this:

```
> buttonPainting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

> ```
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         Intent intent = new Intent(FirstAct.this,SecondAct.class);
>         startActivity(intent);
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
buttonPainting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, paintingbutton.class));
    }
});
```